# `aligned` inside `align`: what's causing the ugly whitespace?

Tags: align, split, white-space

I'm trying to use aligned inside align in order to split/align an equation inside a global align.

My code is:

```
\begin{align}
  \vert A \vert &\leq  \frac{1}{\theta^{3}} \int_{u=0}^t  \left|  \int_{s=0}^u c(s) \frac{ \left(  G^{(1)} (ds)  - G^{(2)} (ds)\right)}{H^{(2)}(s)}\right| \left| H^{(1)}(u)  -H^{(2)}(u)  \right|   G^{(1)}(du)\\
  &\leq \begin{aligned}[t]
    \frac{1}{2\theta^{3}} &\int_{u=0}^t \Biggl\{  \left(  \int_0^u c(s)  \frac{ \left(  G^{(1)} (ds)  - G^{(2)} (ds)\right)}{H^{(2)}(s)}  \right)^2\\
    &+\left( H^{(1)}(u)  -H^{(2)}(u)  \right)^2 \Biggr\}  G^{(1)}(du)\\
  \end{aligned}\\
  &\leq \beta \left( \frac{2}{\theta^{7}} \|G^{(1)} - G^{(2)} \|_{[0,\tau]}^2 + \|H^{(1)} - H^{(2)} \|_{[0,\tau]}^2\right).
\end{align}
```

[image: ugly space]

However this results in a very unaesthetic whitespace. Why? And I'm feeling like this is not the best approach so how should I do that?

Comment: You haven't provided a full code but given that `align` usually numbers equations (even if your snapshot doesn't show the equation numbers) I'd say that the first line is simply too long, and the equation number of the first line is being accommodated below it, hence the space. But again, without a complete code it's impossible to say.

Comment: Do you mean complete code including the preamble and class ? Because the snippet's code is included. Equation numbers are disabled and I don't think the line is too long because the hbox isn't overfull (as verified with draft mode). I can provide a mwe but because it won't be the same fonts it will not match perfectly.

Comment: In a standard set-up, your code does not produce the output you show, so whatever is going on is due to code you are withholding. If I copy your snippet in a minimal document I get precisely the same spacing, but with equation numbers, which BTW explains perfectly where the spacing is coming from. The line does not need to be overfull, just too long to accommodate the equation number on the same line. You say that the equation numbers are disabled, and without knowing *how* you are doing it we can only guess.

Comment: Equation numbers are disabled with \mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs, mathic}. So it would mean the equation number is stil "there". Just invisible? I tested with align* and everything is perfect. I learned something...

Comment: The first line is too long, so the equation number has to be lowered. The effect is exacerbated by the top `aligned`.

Comment: I found the answer in mathtools's doc: "BUG 1:Unfortunately the use of the showonlyref introduce a bug within amsmath’s typesetting of formula versus equation number." page 12 if you want to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the spacing issue you've come across is related to the use (or non-use) of the `showonlyrefs` option of the `mathtools` package. Instead, it is -- as already pointed out by @egreg in a comment -- caused by the fact that the first line is too long. The remedy? Either introduce an explicit line break, or be a bit more circumspect about how the large delimiters are displayed and spaced.

The following screenshot first shows the three equations with `showonlyrefs=true`, and then with `showonlyrefs=false`. The underlying equations are the same in both cases. Note the use of the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro of the `mathtools` package to create macros called `\abs` and `\norm` as well as the avoidance of `\left` and `\right`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\begin{document}

\noindent with \verb+showonlyrefs=true+
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}
\begin{align}
\abs{A} &\leq  \frac{1}{\theta^{3}} \int_{u=0}^t  
  \abs[\bigg]{ \int_{s=0}^u \! c(s) 
    \frac{ G^{(1)} (ds)  - G^{(2)} (ds)}{H^{(2)}(s)}} 
  \abs[\big]{ H^{(1)}(u) - H^{(2)}(u) } \, G^{(1)} (du) \\
  &\leq \frac{1}{2\theta^{3}} \int_{u=0}^t 
    \begin{aligned}[t]
    &\biggl\{ \biggl( \int_0^u c(s)  
    \frac{  G^{(1)} (ds)  - G^{(2)} (ds)}{H^{(2)}(s)}  \biggr)^{\!2} \\
    &\quad+\bigl( H^{(1)}(u) - H^{(2)}(u)  \bigr)^2 \biggr\}\,  G^{(1)}(du)
    \end{aligned}\\
  &\leq \beta \Bigl( \frac{2}{\theta^{7}} 
    \norm[\big]{G^{(1)} - G^{(2)} }_{[0,\tau]}^2 + 
    \norm[\big]{H^{(1)} - H^{(2)} }_{[0,\tau]}^2 \Bigr)\,.
\end{align}

\bigskip
\noindent with \verb+showonlyrefs=false+
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=false}
\begin{align}
\abs{A} &\leq  \frac{1}{\theta^{3}} \int_{u=0}^t  
  \abs[\bigg]{ \int_{s=0}^u \! c(s) 
    \frac{ G^{(1)} (ds)  - G^{(2)} (ds)}{H^{(2)}(s)}} 
  \abs[\big]{ H^{(1)}(u) - H^{(2)}(u) } \, G^{(1)} (du) \\
  &\leq \frac{1}{2\theta^{3}} \int_{u=0}^t 
    \begin{aligned}[t]
    &\biggl\{ \biggl( \int_0^u c(s)  
    \frac{  G^{(1)} (ds)  - G^{(2)} (ds)}{H^{(2)}(s)}  \biggr)^{\!2} \\
    &\quad+\bigl( H^{(1)}(u) - H^{(2)}(u)  \bigr)^2 \biggr\}\,  G^{(1)}(du)
    \end{aligned}\\
  &\leq \beta \Bigl( \frac{2}{\theta^{7}} 
    \norm[\big]{G^{(1)} - G^{(2)} }_{[0,\tau]}^2 + 
    \norm[\big]{H^{(1)} - H^{(2)} }_{[0,\tau]}^2 \Bigr)\,.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```